# Issue with " in a findall statement

Tags: python, regex, findall

I'm running into an issue with the use of " in a regex findall statement in python searching html source code.

I am searching some html source code and can't seem to get quotes (") to work in the findall statement. Due to certain requirements that cannot be changed i am unable to use external libraries like beautifulsoup to help with the searching. I have changed variable names to search.

```
from re import *

def suncorp_find():

    # Setup to find information
    suncorp_file = open('suncorp.html')
    contents_suncorp = suncorp_file.read()

    # Search the HTMl files to find the data
    suncorp_titles = findall(r"\"event-title\">(\w )+", contents_suncorp)

    print(suncorp_titles)

suncorp_find()
```

I am expecting to get a list with items within it but i just get an empty list. When searching for just event-title i get multiple items with the search_titles list.

Thanks in advance for any help

```
<h6 class="event-title">Queensland Reds v Jaguares</h6>
```

Comment: What is the sample input?

Comment: Try to quote symbols: `\\"event-title\\">([\w ]+)`

Comment: I have added a link to the html source code, i also tried the quoting the symbols but that didn't work either

Comment: Please include the sample input in the question itself, and in plain text; not in a link to an image. Also include exactly what your expected output is.

Comment: With the given sample input, I get `['Queensland Reds v Jaguares']`. Is that not what you're looking for?

Comment: Well, your code *did* produce that output, but your last edits broke it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should quote `"` symbol.

```
from re import findall

tmp = """<some_tag name="event-title">Some text 1</some-tag>
<some_tag name="event-title">Some text 2</some-tag>
<some_tag name="event-title">Some text 3</some-tag>"""

result = findall("\"event-title\">([\w ]+)", tmp)
```

Output:

```
['Some text 1', 'Some text 2', 'Some text 3']
```

P.S. I recommend you to use [regex test website](https://regex101.com/r/brhDkj/1) to validate your expressions.

Comment: This can't be the solution - `"\"event-title\">([\w ]+)"` is exactly identical to the literal used in the question `'"event-title">([\w ]+)'`

Comment: For some reason this doesn't work, the code works when testing in a regex tester, but when ran in python it doesn't work.

Comment: @Lachiesterling, try to debug code and check value of `contents_search` before you call `findall()`.

Comment: @ChristophBurschka, yes, you're right, I've missed that he used single quote.

Comment: I have tested this code and it doesn't work, please see the above linked image which shows exactly what i am searching

Comment: @Lachiesterling, I don't want to reprint this text manually. Do not post an image of text. Never.

Comment: Sorry, i have updated the question to include the html source code at the bottom of the op in plain text

Comment: I've tested with your code and it works. `findall()` you're using included from `re`?

Comment: Sorry for the mess around i have posted the exact code i am working from, i don't understand why this isnt working

Comment: Your code working normally, check values of variables before applying regex

Comment: After debugging the code it turns out that it was an issue with the html source code and how it was interpreted by python that was the issue, the code that you suggested would have worked if what i was looking for had event-title, but when python interpreted the html source code it changed to <span> for some reason. Thanks for your help and sorry for my naiveness.

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex:

```
suncorp_titles = findall(r"\"event-title\">(\w.*?)<", contents_suncorp)
```

Or why not below?? I have removed `\w` check. I don't know whether you really need it.

```
suncorp_titles = findall(r"\"event-title\">(.*?)<", contents_suncorp)
```

I took input:

```
<h6 class="event-title">Queensland Reds v Jaguares</h6>
<h6 class="event-title">testing line two</h6>
```

Output:

```
['Queensland Reds v Jaguares', 'testing line two']
```

Comment: After debugging my code i found out that the html file was modified when python interpreted it for some reason and event-title was turned into <span>, i have no idea why this happened and seems really weird but thanks for your reply.